# When filter_input returns not correct cookie value

Tags: php, cookies

I set cookie by this code

```
setcookie($cookieName, $value);
```

And get cookie by this

```
filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, $cookieName);
```

But I get wrong value. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look how you use the code written by you, if you perform both actions on one script, then this is a logical result. Try this instead:

Set cookie:

```
setcookie($cookieName, $value);
```

Update your web page. And then get cookie:

```
filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, $cookieName);
```

Hope this is resolve your issue.